# Confusion regarding network speed distribution

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I don't know what I am writing but I will try my best to explain my query.
I use two ways to connect to internet currently, one through **Wi-Fi** through my mobile network and other using my **LAN** connection. When I download or browse anything, I get a net speed of around **900KBps** and **50KBps** through **mobile network and LAN** respectively. Now the thing is that if I open another browser and download anything speed distributes for mobile network, say **450Kbps, 450KBps** each but for LAN it remains **50KBps, 50KBps** for both. So, if I use (say 8 browsers), total speed for mobile network remains **900KBps** but for LAN it becomes **400KBps** (50KBps*8). I was experimenting and found that my LAN can give upto **1.6MBps**.

***I want to know how to use those 1.6 MBps in a single instance (means in a single browser or single instance of terminal)?***

Comment: This is a bit strange - it sounds like traffic shaping by your router or ISP to limit a single connection's throughput... who is your ISP, and what is your router?

Comment: @Attie, Well, I use my institute's LAN and it limits speed this way.